# HTML from MVC partial page on ASPX (web form)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a big ASP.Net forms application. I am trying to start adding MVC for new stuff. 
But still there are summary pages (in ASPX) where multiple user controls are displayed.

SO I need to embed HTML output of mvc partial page (added as area in existing asp.net web forms app) to ASPX page where other forms user controls are displayed

One way is to get HTML in code behind by initiating http request and place it in literal control.

Other approach i thought was to use JavaScript, but that may not work with convert to PDF etc scenarios.

Please suggest if there is a better way..

Thanks,
Rahul Jain

Comment: Issue a jQuery AJAX request to a controller action that returns the partial view? I don't know what a "convert to PDF scenario" is but that sounds like a totally different question to me.

Comment: thanks.. we generate pdf by converting html to pdf bytes at server side.  like htmlbyptes = Server.execute(pageurl)    then convertHtmltoPDF(htmlBytes)

Comment: so this may not wait for asyc javascript calls

Comment: With most tools creating PDF from html there is "wait for input" duration.. we may have to adjust that to ensure entire html is downloaded (including images, and scripts) and scripts complete rendering